# rename column values using another data

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to rename column data.

for example

I have under dataset.

```
change_name <- data.frame(org_name = c("a", "b", "c"), new_name = c("A", "B", "C"))
dt <- data.frame(name = c("a", "b", "c"), data = c(1, 2, 3))
```

`dt` dataset column `name` change using `change_name` dataset
and want to get like the under dataset.

```
dt <- data.frame(name = c("A", "B", "C"), data = c(1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: You could make `change_name` into a [lookup table](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html#applications) `dt$name <- setNames(change_name$new_name, change_name$org_name)[dt$name]` or if you literally just need to capitalize, use `toupper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `match`

```
dt$name <- change_name$new_name[match(dt$name, change_name$org_name)]
```

Comment: I want to use under the case, too. 

    change_name <- data.frame(org_name = c("a", "b", "c"), new_name = c("honda", "BMW", "toyota"))

Comment: @ogawa  My solution is based on the question you asked i.e. `dt dataset column name change using change_name dataset`

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem use under the code, too.

```
dt$name <- 
  plyr::mapvalues(dt$name, change_name$org_name, change_name$new_name
```